# The foreach loop is skipping the first 2 of 3 items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, algorithm

I was wondering whether you guys could help me figure out why this isn't generating the HTML correctly. The variable `$wholeTeam` is returned from `$wpdb->get_results(...)`  and is confirmed to be of length 3 (because `echo count($wholeTeam)` is spitting that number out and I've directly looked in the MySQL db to make sure there are 3 rows). For some reason, only the last of the 3 is being generated; the first 2 aren't.

```
    <h2>Current members <span class="title-count"> <?php echo count($wholeTeam) ?> </span></h2>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $sandwichTop = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="/assets/';
        $sandwichBottom = '/><button type="button" class="edit-mem-btn wp-core-ui button-primary">Edit</button></div>';
        foreach ($wholeTeam as $thisMember)
            $sandwichMiddle = $thisMember->picfn . '" id="memberid-' . $thisMember->id . '"';
            echo $sandwichTop . $sandwichMiddle . $sandwichBottom;
        ?>
    </div>
```

gets generated as

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img src="/assets/thepic.png" id="memberid-3"/>
          <button type="button" class="edit-mem-btn wp-core-ui button-primary">Edit</button></div>      
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Add `{}` with your foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
foreach ($wholeTeam as $thisMember)
    $sandwichMiddle = $thisMember->picfn . '" id="memberid-' . $thisMember->id . '"';
    echo $sandwichTop . $sandwichMiddle . $sandwichBottom;
```

is equivalent to:

```
foreach ($wholeTeam as $thisMember) {
    $sandwichMiddle = $thisMember->picfn . '" id="memberid-' . $thisMember->id . '"';
}
echo $sandwichTop . $sandwichMiddle . $sandwichBottom;
```

That's why you echo only once. If you want to echo every `foreach` iteration:

```
foreach ($wholeTeam as $thisMember) {
    $sandwichMiddle = $thisMember->picfn . '" id="memberid-' . $thisMember->id . '"';
    echo $sandwichTop . $sandwichMiddle . $sandwichBottom;
}
```